# Can this multi action Jquery be simplified?

Tags: jquery

Okay I'm still pretty new but improving and I've built this script which switches out multiple divs when you click different buttons, but I plan on extending this to use 20 different buttons to switch out 20 different divs so can it be simplified too not be a massive script.

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="salt"></div>
    <div id="pepper"></div>
    <div id="mustard"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="salt-div"> SALT </div>
    <div class="pepper-div"> PEPPER </div>
    <div class="mustard-div"> MUSTARD </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#salt-button').click(function() {
        $('.salt-div').show();
        $('.pepper-div').hide();
        $('.mustard-div').hide();
        $('#salt-button').css('background', '#F1F1F1');
        $('#pepper-button').css('background', 'none');
        $('#mustard-button').css('background', 'none');
      });

      $('#pepper-button').click(function() {
        $('.pepper-div').show();
        $('.salt-div').hide();
        $('.mustard-div').hide();
        $('#pepper-button').css('background', '#F1F1F1');
        $('#salt-button').css('background', 'none');
        $('#mustard-button').css('background', 'none');
      });

      $('#mustard-button').click(function() {
        $('.mustard-div').show();
        $('.salt-dev').hide();
        $('.pepper-div').hide();
        $('#mustard-button').css('background', '#F1F1F1');
        $('#salt-button').css('background', 'none');
        $('#pepper-button').css('background', 'none');
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you also add your HTML to the question

Comment: is someone on a markdown rampage? "Thanks" is removed from my original post and then given a mark down? Anyway I've added the HTML as requested. Thanks

Comment: @Chobbit Don't take it personally. We remove things like "Thanks" as it is not useful to people visiting this question in the future. I wasn't the downvoter so I can't help you there.

Comment: Down vote was likely due to not initially having the html in the question. IMHO but +1 from me now that you have it :)

Comment: @no problem makes sense, thanks :)

Comment: js does not match the html, there is no #salt-button element in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give all your blocks an extra common class name such as `item-block`, and all your buttons a common class such as `item-button`, then when a button is clicked hide all the blocks and show the one you require by adding that info to the button using a `data` attribute;

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="item-button" data-block-id="salt-div" id="salt"></div>
    <div class="item-button" data-block-id="pepper-div" id="pepper"></div>
    <div class="item-button" data-block-id="mustard-div" id="mustard"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="salt-div" class="item-block"> SALT </div>
    <div id="pepper-div" class="item-block"> PEPPER </div>
    <div id="mustard-div" class="item-block"> MUSTARD </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$('.item-button').click(function () {
    var block_id = $(this).data('block-id');
    $('.item-block').hide();
    $('#'+block_id).show();
    $('.item-button').css('background', 'none');
    $(this).css('background', '#F1F1F1');
});
```

Comment: I like this except, items are hidden by a class **item-block** that is not associated with the buttons.  I personally feel that this is a bit dangerous and that the items should be hidden based on the **data-block-id** of the buttons with your **item-button** class.

Comment: @JonSG I disagree. The intent is to show only one element at a time. If you clicked, `salt-div`, you wouldnt want to have to loop through all of the other possible selectors hiding all the other elements one at a time. This way you hide them all, then show only the one whose selector was chosen. One could argue that you should use a more specific selector like `$('#list-1 .item-button')` in the event there are multiple lists, but otherwise this approach is sound.

Comment: This solution requires one to more explicitly know that .item-block is/are associated with .item-button and that in fact, "all" .item-blocks are.  This makes it impossible to support two such sets of buttons on a page without the definition of more item-block style classes.  In my opinion this is brittle.

Comment: Well just wanted to get back that even if others are finding possible downfalls in the code, I have worked this in to my page with all the other scripts and functionalities and it works flawlessly for me. Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway to add on to this code to hide the currently open clock if the currently active button is clicked again? Thanks

Comment: @Chobbit What you need to do is add a class onto the button when it's active (eg `addClass('active')`) and remove it when it isn't; then you can check to see if the button has the class (`$(this).hasClass('active')`) and if it is act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

> *but I plan on extending this to use 20 different buttons to switch out 20 different divs so can it be simplified too not be a massive script.*

With that goal in mind, I would suggest that you change the concept here. Instead of Creating 20 different divs and managing all, I would create one div and modify it according to the button clicked.

One way to do this would be to create an object to hold all of the values for each div then make your buttons and give each one a data attribute (I would actually use a select box myself). When a button is clicked, use the attribute value to retrieve the appropriate content from the storage object.

Something like this:

```js
var divs={
 'salt-div':{text:'salt-div', background:'#1c90f3'},
 'peper-div':{text:'peper-div', background:'#F1F1F1'},
 'mustard-div':{text:'mustard-div', background:'#e0aae6'},
};

$('.change-div').click(function(){
  var kind=$(this).data('kind');
 
 $('#my-div').text( divs[kind].text ).css('background-color', divs[kind].background );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div"></div><br>
<button class="change-div" data-kind="salt-div">Change to salt-div</button>
<button class="change-div" data-kind="peper-div">Change to peper-div</button>
<button class="change-div" data-kind="mustard-div">Change to mustard-div</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add separate `div's` for buttons. we can use the buttons as it is without adding additional `classes`.

Add `data-id` attribute to your buttons with the name of the `content div` . Maintained the same names for the content div as class name`enter code here`.

On button click i'm getting the `data-id` attribute value. Showing the div with the captured value.

```js
$('#content > div').hide();
$('#buttons button').click(function(e) {
    var clickedValue = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('button').removeAttr('style');
  $('#content div').not('#'+clickedValue).hide();
  $(this).css('background','#f1f1f1');
  $('#'+clickedValue).show();
});
```

```css
body{margin:10px;}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-id="salt-div">salt</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-id="pepper-div">pepper</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-id="mustard-div">mustard</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="salt-div"> SALT </div>
    <div id="pepper-div"> PEPPER </div>
    <div id="mustard-div"> MUSTARD </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this may work, it's not the intended use of the `for` attribute   Quote from [the specification:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)

*This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.*

Comment: @DelightedD0D Taken your suggestion and will remember the tip you suggested while i'm implementing in my projects to. Thanks.

Comment: You definitely have the right idea, just that a `data` attribute would be more appropriate, :) cheers.

Comment: In addition to swapping out the use of **for** I would not recommend hiding the **divs** based on being a child of a parent container.  This seems brittle to me.  Since the buttons already define what divs should be hidden and displayed, why not use that information instead?

Comment: @JonSG indeed, that is asking for issues later

Comment: @DelightedD0D changed the attribute `for` to `data`.

Comment: @JonSG Removed css and hiding the content through script only.

Comment: This works great too and I can understand it thanks, sadly I just like worldofjr that little bit more as it just seemed that little but simpler for me. Appreciate it again and keep helping :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to click on divs as you've written in the question, then this works:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="salt">s</div>
    <div id="pepper">p</div>
    <div id="mustard">m</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="salt-div"> SALT </div>
    <div id="pepper-div"> PEPPER </div>
    <div id="mustard-div"> MUSTARD </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#buttons div').on("click", function(e) {
        var clickedid = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#content div').each(function() {
            if($( this ).attr('id') == clickedid + "-div") $(this).css('background', '#F1F1F1').show();
            else $(this).css('background', 'none').hide();
        });
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: "*...this script which switches out multiple divs when you click different buttons...*"

Comment: Yes, however he does go on to use divs for buttons in his example code. My answer doesn't assume that's an error, especially since I've been in situations that needed divs for buttons, myself.

Answer (score -1):

In short, you need to unify all your blocks to common classname and then just operate this classname on click event. Something like this will guide you with slight per your need modifications:

```
var allBlocks = $('.item-block');
$('.item-block').click(function () {
    $('.item-block').not(this).addClass('whatever');
});

.whatever {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I might be being really dumb here but I'm not seeing in the code how clicking individual buttons shows a specific div but hides all other specific divs. Again I might be being noobish but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: You're affecting the buttons themselves, not the divs